# Directly load elasticsearch index data in json file of kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm working on kibana and elasticsearch. I want to include path of elasticsearch index data (where data is stored after indexing) in a json file of kibana dashboard so that when I run kibana, logs will automatically be loaded without using logstash conf file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please provide your relevant code?

Comment: Make sure that you have an actual question!